# Seeing SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I wanted server and client communication to happen via SSL . I have followed this [link](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/j-jsse/j-jsse-ltr.pdf). 
It says generate keypair and then generate server.private and server.public. Now when I run my server and client program, the server program exits with:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 679
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
```

I read many questions on SO and guessed I need to run :
keytool -import -alias example -keystore cacerts -file root.cer.

But what values do I give for the above command ? My private and public keys for server and client are server.public, server.private, client.public, client.private.